# c++ non fully constructed object deallocation

Tags: c++, exception

**Code :**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
    A(){cout << "A() Constructor " << endl;
        throw 1;
    }

};


int main(){
A* p=0;
cout << p << endl; // p value is 0
try{
p=new A(); // object is not fully constructed, no address is returned to p. for future deallocation

}
catch(...){cout << "Exception" << endl;}
cout << p << endl; // this will output that p has the value 0,proof that no address was returned to p.


}
```

memory is allocated for A object in the heap, the address of the memory is passed to the constructor
but when the constructor `throw 1;` then object of type `A` will not considered to be a fully constructed object. so no
pointer will be returned the pointer p. feel free to correct me if I've understood something wrong.
**Questions:**
**1)** So my question is how it is possible in such case to deallocate memory for the A object. Im not talking about
The destructor call, but the deallocation of memory.
**2)** what about when I create a local object of type `A` inside `main` function. and obviously it wont be fully constructed either. when does this object get deallocated (ofcourse after calling the destructor of fully construted subobjects ).

Comment: you cant delete it because p is the null pointer, and the address of memory that the object A was allocated in, didn't get passed to this pointer because of the exception that was thrown inside the A constructor

Comment: The right way to do it is called shared pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The allocation done by `new A()` consists of multiple steps:

1. Allocate memory using `operator new(sizeof(A))`.
2. Try to default construct an object in the allocated memory.
3. When default construction fails, `operator delete(x)` is called with the address obtained earlier.

More generally, if you use an overloaded `operator new()`, e.g., `new(allocator) A()` which calls `operator new(size_t, Alloctor)` (where `allocator` is convertible to `Allocator`), a corresponding `operator delete()` is called.

As part of exception throwing, all partially constructed subobjects are destroyed (in the reverse order in which they were constructed) as well. That is, if an exception is thrown from the constructor of an object, you don't need to care about clean-up (assuming, all subobjects correctly look after the resources they have allocated). This is true independent on whether the object is allocated on the heap or the stack.

Comment: what if I have "A* p" inside my class, and I initialize this pointer with p=new A(); I was going to deallocate this memory from the ~A() destructor. so since A() constructor throws an exception which prevent it's destructor to get called, I can't deallocate the memory that p point to. what should I do in this situation ?

Comment: You should make sure each of your members looks after itself! Instead of explicitly `delete`ing the memory you could use a `std::auto_ptr<A>` or a `std::unique_ptr<A>`. ... or even use a member directly in your object: If the type is always `A` there may be no need to have an extra allocation at all.

Comment: thanks. but im not looking for an alternative solution. I just want to know if I will have a memory leak in the case explained above when the destructor of the object isn't going to be called which was respensible for deallocation of some dynamic allocated memory.

Comment: If you store a raw pointer to memory not `delete`d otherwise you eould have a memory leak: destroying a raw pointer doesn't do anything. Thus, you shouldn't use a raw pointer to memory you need to release. The alternative is to catch exceptions in the constructor and do the clean-up in the `catch`-block but this gets quickly very messy.

Comment: BTW: the `new(allocator)` form is called `placement new`, and the matching operator delete is called `placement delete` function (or operator).

Answer (score 5):

1) The deallocation is done for you.

2) If it's a local object it never got allocated in the first place.

Comment: for local object, why it wont get allocated in the first place. from what I know local object get allocated when the flow of execution enter the scope they exist in, after that the constructor get called on that memory. so they already got allocated when the execution entered the scope. so how it's possible that they wont be allocated in the first place ?

Comment: I can agree with you about the existence of the object. the object never exist if it's constructor fail, but that doesn't mean it didn't get allocated (in memory). and this is the same for both local and dynamic object. feel free to correct me if I've understand something wrong.

Comment: For me allocation means heap allocation with new or malloc. Obviously local objects have to get put somewhere in memory but how this happens is not something you have any control over, so it's not something you need to worry about. It just happens and it just works.

Answer (score 5):

When a constructor throws the memory allocated for that object is automatically released, btw the destructor is not called.  You do not need to deallocate.

Comment: yes I know that the destructor will not be called because  the object isn't fully constructed.from your answer. can I understand that there will be a deallocation of memory in both cases,for local object and dynamic allocated one automatically after the constructor throw an exception ?

Comment: Yes. Regardless of how the object is constructed, if the constructor throws the memory will be deallocated automatically

Answer (score 1):

In CPP, the sequence of constructor(ctor) calling is:

- virtual base class：virtual base ctor, calling according to depth first sequence.
- base class: base class calling sequence according to the derived declaration in defining the class.
- Non-static member object
- Derived class ctor;

Destructors (dtor) are called in the reversed order.

CPP ensures the resources of fully constructed object (Not Pointers) will be released.

There is RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization). We use objects to wrap raw pointers to allocate memory, then released the memory in dtor. If the derived object is partially constructed because of (not enough memory, exception etc.), member object dtor will be called.

In the above simple example, there is no resource allocated, so there is no resource leak.

But if there are member pointers which allocate memory before throw, there will be memory leak. If we wrap the memory in a class and make an object of this class as a component (using RAII), then there will be no memory leak .